# Android ViewPagerIndicator errors

Tags: android

Chcę zrobić Android Viewpager as Image Slide Gallery.

I have this ( Unfortunately, I have errors.):

[Code + LogCat](http://pastebin.com/1mpbGDbH)

To moderators: Please paste code here because i can't... I have errors.

Comment: You aren't trying to launch a Fragment as an Activity are you? What does your manifest look like?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/9MWN97Zt Manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are definitely to launch a Fragment as an Activity

```
<activity
        android:name="com.test.PlaceDetailsFragment"
</activity>
```

Fragments are *contained* in Activities; you **cannot** launch a Fragment as an Activity - they're not interchangable. This means that you have to make a SherlockActivity that holds your Fragment (call the Activity `MainActivity` - simple and meaningful name), then you should be able to get everything launched (not guaranteeting the Fragment code is proper, there's too much code to look at).  [Start with this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html), then move on to [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/support-lib.html). They both give you a lot of information about how to properly build android apps. Then once you've grasped the subject, don't forget to change your manifest so it points to the Activity instead.

```
<activity
    android:name="com.test.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Eg, in your main.xml layout, you should have:

```
<fragment   android:name="com.test.PlaceDetailsFragment"
            android:id="@+id/fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity{
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
 }
 

}

Comment: As long as R.layout.main holds a fragment, you should be good. Edited post with what *a fragment declaration in xml* can look like.

Comment: Starts. How to display the fragments now?

Comment: @CousinRomeo what I added to my post should embed it, however, it's up to you to decide how/when to show it. Have a look at the Fragment tutorial I linked.

Comment: Just add what I edited in your layout and see if that works. If it's a simple fragment, it should.

Comment: ok I change MainActivity extends Activity and add fragment to main.xml but now I have errors: http://pastebin.com/Vhm0xZiK

Comment: Nono, leave it for SherlockActivity

Comment: @CousinRomeo please try something yourself. I can only help so much. If you added the `fragment` stuff in your MainActivity layout xml, that's all I can help with.

Comment: One last question. I have to add fragments to Manifest.xml? If so how do you just <activity>?

Comment: @CousinRomeo fragments are **never** added to the manifest, they are simply UI Components that are used in Activities. Think of a Dialog for example. That's not declared in the manifest - and is used by Activities.